# Multi-module Springboot Kotlin inside Docker with Spring DevTools

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, devtools

I have a multi module project using spring-boot2 and i already dockerized it but the problem is when i compile my source code in the host using `mvn clean install` the submodules are not recompiled inside the docker but the application restart and i am using spring devtools the three module in additional-paths are compiled but not changed in the application.

here`s my config on devtools

```
  devtools:
    restart:
      log-condition-evaluation-delta: false
      pollInterval: 10s
      additional-paths: ../builds,../domain,../persistence
```